# std::string constructor throws std::out_of_range exception

Tags: c++, exception, stdstring

Using VS 2012.

I was making hangman. Anyway, I had a function to get a std::string that was the same length as the current word being guessed, but filled with underscores. (as in, blanks).

The function:

```
std::string getBlankWord(std::vector<std::string> words, int currentWordIndex)
{
    return std::string(words[currentWordIndex], '_');
}
```

The line it is called on:

```
currentGuessingString = getBlankWord(words, index);
```

words is an std::vector, index is an int. words.size() = 22, and index = 0, so I don't know how calling, in this case, words[0] could be the culprit.  Anyway, something on this line throws std::out_of_range exception, but I cannot find it.

Thanks.

Comment: [Fascinating](http://ideone.com/clone/Nt7pS7)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `std::string(const std::string&, int)` constructor O.o  It totally exists though: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: Also, `getBlankWord` should take the vector by const reference: `const std::vector<std::string>& words`, or else it will copy the whole array each time you call the function :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the fascinating part - it holds 22 strings, thus the size is 22? Also, yes, I thought of that, but I planned to optimize it after I was sure the code would stay in there (as is, you don't notice speed problems, but only 22 words)

Comment: Fascinating because I really expected that code to result in a compiler error, but it actually performs exactly how you described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem appears because the constructor that ends up being called is the substring constructor (see [here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/))

The first argument is easy to figure out, the second one however will be a char with the ascii value of '_' implicitly casted to a size_t and its' value is most likely bigger than the size of the string you are giving to the constructor which in turn causes your problem

Answer (score 5):

I think what you really want here is more like:

```
return std::string(words[currentWordIndex].size(), '_');
```

Comment: And why was the out of bounds exception occurring?

Comment: @MooingDuck because '_' is 242 in ascii. It copies 242 characters from the passed string.

Comment: @PeterWood: ASCII only has 128 characters, and `_` is #95.  I can see several pages listing `_` as 242 in some codepage, but I can't figure out which codepage that is.

Comment: @MooingDuck Sorry, my mistake. I was looking at extended ascii, it is indeed [95](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/underscore-understrike-underbar-low-line-ascii-code-95.html) in ascii printable codes.

Comment: @PeterWood: I'm still interested in your comment.  I figured you meant extended ascii, and found [this](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/underline-underscore-ascii-code-242.html), but interestingly, that page claims the extension is code page 437, but when I look up that code page, it has `≥` at that position instead!

Comment: [Code Page 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252), and [ISO 8859](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859) both have `242` as some variation of `o` with an accent `ò`. [Code Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Standard_code_page) has `242` as `≥`, [Code Page 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) has it as the underscore `‗`, which strangely is sometimes displayed as a double line.

Comment: Actually, my explanation is wrong, the constructor copies characters from position `95` until the end of the string, not 95 characters as I previously said.